# Как с jquery отсекать неправильный тип данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Прошу помощи, задача сложить все что в value c классом num.
Проблемы возникают если в value попадает '-' или 'пусто' вместо числа, тогда sum принимает пустое значение. Как сделать преобразование, чтобы если в value некорректный символ попадает или отрицательное число, то они преобразовывались в ноль?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='2'>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='3'>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='-'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
 var sum = 0;
 $('.num').each(function(){
   sum += parseInt($(this).val());  
 });
 console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [логической операцией ИЛИ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description). Которая возвращает первый операнд, которые приводится к true.

в данном случае, в результате вызова [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), при неудаче будет возвращено `NaN`, которое проводится к `false`.

Следовательно можно воспользоваться следующей записью:

```
 var sum = 0;
 $('.num').each(function(){
   sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;  // если не число - прибавляем 0
 });
 console.log(sum);
```

Пример:

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.num').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='2'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='3'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' class='num' name='num1' value='-'>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.num').each(function(){
  var value = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && value > 0)
    sum += value;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Разбить на две операции

```
// побитовое "или" вернет цифру если она есть, в любом другом случае ноль
var a = $this.val() | 0;
// Проверка на отрицательное значение
sum += a < 1 ? 0 : a;
```