# jquery - как удалить class у следующего тега?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите въехать пожалуйста. Есть такой html.

```
<span>ddd</span><button id="a" class="aaa bbb"><i class="ccc eee"></i></button>
```

Фрагмент js

```
$('#a').removeClass('aaa');
```

Как мне дополнить, чтобы в этой же строке удаляло класс "ссс" у тега  который внутри этого button и полностью тег span перед button ?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/881658/176262

Comment: А мне казалось что это в два счета находится в интернете

Comment: Вам явно нужно почитать раздел о jQuery - выбор объектов по селектору

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#a').removeClass('aaa').find("i").removeClass('ccc');
```

---

> как если перед button еще  который целиком надо удалить

```js
$('#a').click(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('aaa').find("i").removeClass('ccc').closest("button").prev("span").remove();
});
```

```css
.ccc {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>ddd</span>
<button id="a" class="aaa bbb">
  <i class="ccc eee">Test</i>
</button>
```

---

> не целиком span, а только текст внутри него удалить

```js
$('#a').click(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('aaa').find("i").removeClass('ccc').closest("button").prev("span").text("");
});
```

```css
.ccc {
  color: green;
}

.span-class {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span-class">ddd</span>
<button id="a" class="aaa bbb">
  <i class="ccc eee">Test</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как если  перед button еще <span></span> который целиком надо удалить?

Comment: и все одной строкой

Comment: @IZrchnsk Добавьте, пожалуйста, html в вопрос.

Comment: как то он не сразу удаляется... а по повторнуму действию

Comment: @IZrchnsk У меня - сразу.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @IZrchnsk Пожалуйста. Успехов!